# LARAVEL - Edit function in tab view

Tags: php, laravel

Asking for your help please. I want to show different Applicants on different tabs in my edit.blade.php, I just wondering how can I do that? Please help me.

**Controller.php**

```
public function edit($id)
   {
       $applications = application::where('id', $id)->first();

       return view('user.application.edit', compact('applications'));
   }
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {{ request()->is('applicant1') ? 'active' : null }}" href="{{ url('applicant1') }}" role="tab">Main Applicant</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {{ request()->is('applicant2') ? 'active' : null }}" href="{{ url('applicant2') }}" role="tab">Applicant 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {{ request()->is('applicant3') ? 'active' : null }}" href="{{ url('applicant3') }}" role="tab">Applicant 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-pane {{ request()->is('applicant1') ? 'active' : null }}" id="{{ url('applicant1') }}" role="tabpanel">
//FORM HERE
</div>
```

**web.php** I was trying different approaches on routes too.

```
      Route::get('applicant1', 'ApplicationController@edit')->name('application.edit');


      Route::get ('/applicant2', function () {
            return view('application.edit');});      
            
      Route::get ('/applicant3', function () {
            return view('application.edit');});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` in anchor element,  like `<a target="_blank" class="nav-link" ……… </a>`

Comment: Hi Talha, still encountering the same problem. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a foreach for each applicant element?

In your controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $applications = application::all();

    return view('user.application.edit', compact('applications'));
}
```

I your view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
@foreach($applications as $applicant)
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ request('id') == $applicant->id ? 'active' : ''}}" href="{{ route('application.edit', $applicant->id) }}" role="tab">Main Applicant</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
@foreach($applications as $applicant)
    // the rest of panels
    <div class="tab-pane fade show {{ request('id') == $applicant->id ? 'active' : '' }}" id="tab-{{ $loop->iteration }}" role="tabpanel"></div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

In your routes.php

```
Route::get('applicants/{id}', 'ApplicationController@edit')->name('application.edit');
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that I was getting data from 2 different tables. application and additionaapplications and joining them using application_id

Comment: use the corresponding relation, in this case: `$applications = application::with('additionaapplications ')->get(); `